# Magento 2: How to include my jquery lib in admin

Tags: magento2, magento2-dev-beta

How can i include my jQuery lib files in magento 2.

**Updated**

```
         <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthenticationPopup" name="authentication-popup" as="authentication-popup" template="account/authentication-popup.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="authenticationPopup" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Customer/js/view/authentication-popup</item>
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="messages" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/view/messages</item>
                                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">messages</item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
```

How dependencies of this file is set and how  they getting added

Comment: there is more examples here about layout files and how to add jquery libs you can check them https://wiki.magento.com/display/MAGE2DOC/Managing+Page+Markup+Using+XML+Layout

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are working with a module, from your layout file like this:

app/code/Learning/Customer/view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="Learning_Customer::js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" src_type="url"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Comment: Using this way you can add the js file but you can not set  its dependencies

Comment: plz check the updated question

Answer (score 0):

app/code/Training/Modulename/view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>      
        <script src="Training_Modulename::js/fancybox.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Add fancybox.js inside view/Adminhtml/web/js/fancybox.js